# Numpy indexing broadcasting introduces new dimension

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-indexing

I have an array I wan to use for mapping. Let's call it `my_map` ,type float shape (m,c).

I have a second array with indexes, lest call it `my_indexes`, type int size (n,c), every value is between 0 and m.

Trying to index `my_map` doing `my_ans = my_map[my_indexes]` I get an array of shape (n,c,c), when I was expecting (n,c). What would be the proper way to do it?

Just to be clear, what I am trying to do is something equivalent to:

```py
my_ans = np.empty_like(touch_probability)
for i in range(c):
    my_ans[:,i] = my_map[:,i][my_indexes[:,i]]
```

Comment: Not sure how you're trying to index the ndarray. But think about this, when you slice `my_map` with say `my_map[3]`, just any integer, this returns an array ( the fourth row of `mymap`)
. If you slice it with a `1d` array, you will get a `2d` array. And if you attempt to slice it with a `2d` array, which is what you're doing, you will get a `3d` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate and test your problem, define simple, real arrays:

```
In [44]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [45]: idx = np.array([[0,2,1,0],[2,2,1,0]])
In [46]: arr.shape
Out[46]: (3, 4)
In [47]: idx.shape
Out[47]: (2, 4)
```

Your desired calculation:

```
In [48]: res = np.zeros((2,4), int)
In [49]: for i in range(4):
    ...:     res[:,i] = arr[:,i][idx[:,i]]  # same as arr[idx[:,i], i]

    ...:     
In [50]: res
Out[50]: 
array([[0, 9, 6, 3],
       [8, 9, 6, 3]])
```

Doing the same with one indexing step:

```
In [51]: arr[idx, np.arange(4)]
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 9, 6, 3],
       [8, 9, 6, 3]])
```

This is broadcasting the two indexing arrays against each other, and then picking points:

```
In [52]: np.broadcast_arrays(idx, np.arange(4))
Out[52]: 
[array([[0, 2, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 1, 0]]), 
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]])]
```

So we are indexing the (m,c) array with 2 (n,c) arrays

---

The following are the same:

arr[idx] 
   arr[idx, :]

It is using `idx` to select whole rows from `arr`, so the result is shape of `idx` plus the last dimension of `arr`.  Where as what you want is just the `ith` element of the `idx[j,i]` row.